# Vector drawable crashing on recycler view but working fine on activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, androidx, android-vectordrawable

I have added vector drawable in  my app, and its working fine in activity.

```
ivTeam.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_home_team))
```

but when i execute the same code from recycler adapter which is in a fragment, it crashes and gives following error message.

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f122e

I am passing activity reference to adapter, and also tried following static block.

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

but nothing seems to be working here, i am on androidX, and added following in my my gradle file.

```
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

**Gradle Version:**

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

Comment: Do you have test.xml in your drawable resource folder? If yes is it a valid vector drawable?

Comment: @MichaelDovoh :Yes its a vector drawable and its in `drawable` folder

Comment: Can you show me where you are using it in your adapter

Comment: @dev90 Try setting the `drawable` using `setImageResource()` instead of `setImageDrawable()`.

`ivTeam.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home_team)`

Answer (score 0):

if you are indeed using Android X I suspect you might not be loading your vector drawables correctly

I have read your question shortly after [an article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/using-vector-assets-in-android-apps-4318fd662eb9) which states:

> **Load with AndroidX**
>
> When loading drawables you need to use methods from AndroidX which provide the  backported vector support. The entry point for this is to always load drawables with AppCompatResources.getDrawable. While there are a number of ways to load drawables (because reasons), you must use AppCompatResources if you want to use compat vectors. If you fail to do this, then you won’t hook into the AndroidX code path and your app might crash when trying to use any features not supported by the platform you’re running on.

From your code it appears that you are using ContextCompat.getDrawable instead of AppCompatResources.getDrawable

Using AppCompatResources.getDrawable should correct your issue